# Draw smooth line between geopoints on android

Tags: android, google-maps, draw

I've drawed line between geopoints. its successfully drawed. when we see the map, the drawline look like pixelated when adjecent of next drawling. how to merge the line?

[image]

My code is here,

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
    if(! routeIsActive) return;

    mapview.getProjection().toPixels(locpoint, pp);       // Converts GeoPoint to screen pixels

    int xoff = 0;
    int yoff = 0;
    int oldx = pp.x;
    int oldy = pp.y;
    int newx = oldx + xoff;
    int newy = oldy + yoff;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
    for(int i=0; i<numberRoutePoints-1; i++)
    {
        switch(routeMode.get(i))
        {
        case 0:
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
            break;
        case 1:
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0EA7D6"));
            break;
        case 2:
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#654321"));
            break;
        case 3:
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#123456"));
            break;
        }   

        mapview.getProjection().toPixels(routePoints.get(i), pold);
        oldx = pold.x;
        oldy = pold.y;
        mapview.getProjection().toPixels(routePoints.get(i+1), pnew);
        newx = pnew.x;
        newy = pnew.y;

        canvas.drawLine(oldx, oldy, newx, newy, paint);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the style of the paint object like this:

```
paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you draw a circle at the beginning and the end of each line (the circle diameter must be the line height), I think it will do the trick or maybe [drawRoundRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRoundRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) of the canvas can do it well